# Reading a file and looking for specifc strings

Tags: python-3.x

Hey so my question might be basic but I am a little lost on how to implement it.

If I was reading a file, for example an HTML File. How do I grab a specific parts of the file. For example what I want to do is

```
blahblahblahblah<br>blahblahblah
```

how do I find the tag that starts off with < and ends with > and grab the string inside which is br in Python?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question there are a couple of ways you could retrieve a single string from a `html` file.

First option would be to parse the file with a library like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), this option is also valid for `xml` files too.

Second option would be, if the file is relatively small you could use `regex` to locate a string you want and return it.

First option is what I would recommend, if you use a library like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) you have a lot of functionality, eg. to find the parent element of a selected tag and so on.